# ng-modell in an *ngfor does not show the right value

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel, ngfor

I have an JSON which is loaded into my Angular2 App.

My JSON is called `tempPromotion` and i try to get into `['results']` the following way:

```
tempPromotion['response_payload']['ruleset_list']['results']
```

in `['results']` are 2 values, `['value_path']` and `['calculation']`

my HTML looks like this:

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Value Path</th>
          <th>Result</th>
          <th>TEST</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let result of rule['results']; let x = index">
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="valuePath{{x}}" [(ngModel)]="result['value_path']" name="valuePath{{x}}"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount{{x}}" [(ngModel)]="result['calculation']" name="discount{{x}}"></td>
          <td>{{x}} {{result['calculation']}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

to understand why i use `rule`, this is alreay inside an other *ngfor `<div class="card" *ngFor="let rule of tempPromotion['response_payload']['ruleset_list']; let i = index">`

My output looks like this

```
channel 1 | #Value * 0.8 | 0 #Value * 0.9 
channel 1 | #Value * 0.8 | 1 #Value * 0.8
```

My `[(ngModel)]` shows the wrong value, while my Two-way-binding `{{result['calculation']}}` shows the right value.

Why is this happening and what is the solution for this Problem?

Comment: Maybe you want to come up with a plunker where you could fork off a recent published one in order to get speed on creating it https://plnkr.co/edit/gDrxfK to reproduce what you are doing so far in detail. Often you'll find the issue while creating the plunker ;-)

Comment: @Markus Yeah you where right :) I tried it again on plunker and found my mistake! Nice advice for my future work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

My Problem was that i had the same id / name for my inputs.

change `id="valuePath{{x}}"` to `id="valuePath{{i}}{{x}}"` fixxed it.